# Appending rows of data from one Excel table to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 data sets. Table1 has 209 columns, and Table2 has 123 columns. The columns from Table 2 exist within the columns from Table1, but in no particular order.

I want to append ALL of the data from Table1 to Table2, but for the appropriate fields.

i.e., "Fiscal Year" for Table2 is the 67th column (Column BO), and is the 170th column (Column FN) for Table1

I would like a non-VB, non-add on solution to just having a formula that looks at the Table2 column header, retrieves the appropriate column from Table1, and appends the data from Table1 to Table2.

I was thinking like sort of a Small/If array formula, but I can only wrap my head around how to do that based on vertical criteria, not horizontal criteria. Anyone have any ideas?

Just FYI, I did attempt to import into Access to create an append query, but the dataset has open text fields that have >255 characters, and Access chokes on it.

Comment: You can use Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me you cannot append data from one table to another with formulas. However, what you can do if you have Excel 365, is create a new range that joins the data from both tables.

```
=IFERROR(LET(cols1,SEQUENCE(,COUNTA(Table2[#Headers]),1,1),cols2,MATCH(Table2[#Headers],Table1[#Headers],0),filter1,Table2[#All],rows1,ROWS(filter1),filter2,Table1,rows2,ROWS(filter2),seq,SEQUENCE(rows1+rows2),IF(seq<=rows1,INDEX(filter1,seq,cols1),INDEX(filter2,seq-rows1,cols2))),"")
```

[image]

Now, you can simply select the entire range and `copy/paste` it over your Table2 and it will "update" accordingly.